# Verify that $M_{X}(t) \ge e^{t\mu}$ using Jensen's identity

Tags: probability, jensen-inequality

Suppose that a real valued random variable with a probability density of $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{8}(x+1) &:-1 <x<5\\
0 &: \text{else}
\end{cases}$$.

I need to verify that $M_{X}(t) \ge e^{t\mu}$, where $M_{X}(t)$ is the moment generating function of X, $t=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\mu$ is the mean of the probability density function, using Jensen's inequality.

From what I understand, I need to show that $E[w(X)] \ge w(\mu)$.

My question is what would I use for the value of $w(X)$? would I use $M_{X}(t)$ or should I use the probability density function?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $t$, the function $x\mapsto e^{tx}$ is convex. Hence, Jensen's inequality shows that
$E[e^{tX}]\geq e^{tE[X]}=e^{t\mu}.$

The problem is pretty straightforward in that the left is
$$
\int_{-1}^5 e^{tx}f_X(x)\,dx
$$
and the right is just $e^{t\mu}$ where
$$
\mu=E[X]=\int_{-1}^5 xf_X(x)\,dx.
$$

Comment: That was my suspicion. Thanks for the feedback. Do I need to check for convexity using the second derivative test before using the inequality?

Comment: I mean it's rather trivial since $t^2 e^{tx}>0$.

Comment: Just trying to learn good habits. Regardless of how trivial it is, should it be included in a solution?

Comment: It depends on your level and your course. If this was a research paper, this entire problem would likely not even be a proof at all, but a remark. If this was an introductory probability course at the college level, my suspicion is that it wouldn't hurt to comment on why Jensen's inequality is valid.